# Reading a file line by line using bash, extracting some data. How?

Tags: parsing, shell, text-extraction

I want to read a file a extract information from it based on certain tag. For example :

```
SCRIPT_NAME:mySimpleShell.sh

This is a simple shell. I would like to have this as
Description. I also want to create a txt file our of this.

SCRIPT_NAME:myComplexShell.sh

This is a complex shell. I would like to have this as
Description. I also want to create a txt file our of this.
```

So when I pass in this file to my shell script, my shell will read it line by line and
when it gets to SCRIPT_NAME, It extract it and save it in $FILE_NAME, then starts writing 
the description to a file on disk with $FILE_NAME.txt name. And It does it until It reaches the end of file. If there is 3 SCRIPT_NAME tag, then it creates 3 description file.

Thanks for helping me in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines using a `while` loop. Use a regex to check if a line has `SCRIPT_NAME` and if so, extract the filename. This is shown below:

```
#! /bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ SCRIPT_NAME:(.*$) ]]
    then
        FILENAME="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "Writing to $FILENAME.txt"
    else
        echo "$line" >> "$FILENAME.txt"
    fi
done < inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '/^SCRIPT_NAME:/ { split( $0, a, ":" ); name=a[2]; next }
    name { print > name ".txt" }' ${1?No input file specified}
```